# Royal Slider Different Color Thumbnails

Tags: html, css, wordpress, slider

I am trying to change the color of each thumbnail below the slider on the wordpress royal slider plugin. At the moment they are all the same color.

Here is my HTML markup

```
<div class="rsTmb">
{{html}}
</div>
```

And here is the html code from each off my slides

```
<a class="rsImg"  href="imageurl.png" data-        rsVideo="videorul">title goes here</a>
<div  class="rsTmb" style="background:#108FD2">title goes here</div>
```

Can someone help me have set it up so that i have individual colors for each off the tabs

Comment: I doubt this question will get answered. You need to produce a fiddle or a link to the site or test site. Good luck anyway.

Comment: http://bluetechnologies.co.uk/developing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by adding a click event to the thumbs. In my example I have given the div's an ID and then used that as the color name. You could do it individually by assigning a class if you so wished.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/76Kyz/

HTML

```
    <div id="red" class="rsNavItem rsThumb">
    <div id="blue" class="rsNavItem rsThumb">
    <div id="green" class="rsNavItem rsThumb">
```

jQuery

```
 $('.rsThumb').click(function(){
    $('.rsThumb').css('background', 'none');
    $(this).css('background', this.id);
 });
```